# PickerIcon de smartgwt personalizado

Tags: java, smartgwt

Soy nuevo en java usando smartgwt estuve buscando en internet el como poder crear un PickerIcon con un icono personalizado pero no encontre ningun ejemplo que me fuese util, alguien tendria algun ejemplo pero de como se implementaria, alguien me podria ayudar?

La libreria es com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.PickerIcon;